# Velocity.js removes style attribute after animation completion

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, velocity.js

My Velocity.js animation is being reverted to stylesheet defined values after completion by removing `style` attribute. I've checked all in docs, there isn't anything that gives me a clue.

Simple enough, `span` is styled like this:

```
.csstransforms3d #naslov h1 span{
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
       -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
         -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
            transform: perspective(400px) rotateX(90deg);
}
```

and animated with this:

```
$.Velocity.hook( $('#naslov h1 span') , "rotateX", "90deg");
$('#naslov h1 span').velocity({rotateX:'0deg'},3000)
```

I'm watching my animation in dev tools. Everything goes fine, `transform: rotateX` is gradually lowering it's value in `style` tag of a `span` and - boom, whole `style` tag is gone once `rotateX` reaches 0;

Does anyone know what's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, the default behavior of Velocity is to remove transforms with null-like values, see [here](https://github.com/julianshapiro/velocity/issues/224#issuecomment-51526521).

The problem is that your end value is `0deg` which is the basically a null rotate transform.

Not sure this will work, but I think if you simply **add 360 to all values** you could trick the system into not cleaning the `transform:rotateX` at the end.

**Update:**
As per @Miloshio's comment **it's better to add 0.01 to all values** instead of 360 (not tested).

Comment: I really can't believe this is true. Why in the earth animation library that aim to save every CPU cycle bother to do this, not to mention unexpected, better to say INCORRECT results? Thank you for answer.

Comment: to amend your answer 360 instead 0 deg is incorrect considering element transformation move. **0.01 deg** I found to be adequate but I'm very unsure about potential cross-browser issue with this.

Comment: The reason Velocity does this is because of bugs in browsers, for example one that causes texts/images to be blurry when a transform is applied. However, you're right this needs better handling, hence the long discussion.